# How to make a new LLVM instruction?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to make the instruction

```
%a = i32 add %b, %c
```

into

```
%a = i32 mul %b, %c
```

I have been searching for hours but the answers I have discovered so far are answers that are related to creating new instructions defined in Instructions.h (ex AllocaInst) not mul, sdiv, div, instructions.
I have also read the https://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#creating-and-inserting-new-instructions
but I couldn't get the example "auto *newInst = new Instruction(...);" 
to work because I didn't know what the parameters of the should be even after looking at 
https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#a2b30181f228bc6318130557d7ffca945

EDIT:
I think I have successfully created the instruction itself, but not I'm having trouble replacing it in the right way.

```
Instruction *ni = BinaryOperator::CreateMul(inst.getOperand(0), newvalue);
ReplaceInstWithInst(*i, ni);
```

where *i is from iterating over a basic block (ex for (auto &i : bb))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
Instruction *ni = BinaryOperator::CreateMul(inst.getOperand(0), newvalue);
bb.getInstList().insert(inst.getIterator(), ni);
```

Comment: JFYI. You can do it in one step, see create().

Comment: thanks!
but i think my problem was i was trying to change the instruction that i was iterating over, i replaced the instructions after iteration was over and i was able to get it to work